# Latest XCode .dmg (setup) for fresh install on Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, mac-app-store

I don't have Apple ID (reviewed), as I don't have credit card. So, for sure, I cannot download and install any App form Mac App Store right??

Is there **any archive** from where I can install XCode 4.2 (or say "**latest**") and latest iOS sdk.

I want to install XCode on my Mac, as it was not having XCode when I purchased it.

As per my knowledge, the download and install mechanism for XCode or say any other developer tool did not require Apple Id, previously. Do I really need to have credit card for simple XCode installation ??? Sounds funny.

**Please Note :**  I don't have any other mac, or any resource, who can provide me "Install XCode" file, which Mac App Store gives you after download and install.

Any suggestion ???

Comment: This is a question about iTunes accounts rather than Xcode, and is off topic for SO.

Comment: I was able to register and download free iPhone apps at their appstore without a credit card earlier, has that changed for the Mac Appstore? At least in Sweden you get the option "No credit card" when you sign up.

Comment: @jrturton: I really don't use the iTunes application for download or install Apps. (My fault, accepted) :)

Comment: Krishna, there? Register , Its free....

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: signing is free here, too.

Comment: Tried Everything, but every thing wants my apple id to be reviewed by iTunes Store. :(
Don't know, how you people get it by free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [xcode 4.2.1](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) from App Store. App store need Apple ID for that. If you have no apple id then create new apple id.

Comment: I have Apple Id now. Now When i enter my Id and password, it tells me that: "My Id has not been reviewed yet with iTunes store", While reviewing the Apple Id it is asking me for the Credit card details.

Comment: Can we we discuss in detail in otherway?

Answer (score 0):

**You can download Xcode for free here..**

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12

**Note ..you do require an Apple id..(just do a Free sign up)**

Comment: Note that this is the Lion download.  I have yet to see a link to the Xcode 4.2.1 Snow Leopard download outside of the developer portal.

Comment: I don't find any link there, to start downloading XCode. Rather it's redirecting me to the Mac App Store.

Comment: yes..it will redirect to mac store..that from where you can download..

Comment: Which is asking me the reviewed Apple ID to start download.

Comment: don't know..works for me..and I didn't pay a cent for the Apple id i used.

Comment: Don't think its bad luck.... God do something for every one...

Answer (score 0):

Well to install app from Mac App store you don't need to have a Apple Id .. you need an iTunes account.. and to download a free app from Mac app store using iTunes account you don't need a credit card.

Comment: Let me give it a try, will let you know after.

Comment: It is asking me to review my Apple Id & in this reviewing process they need card details (As compulsory field).

Comment: create a new apple id with free account and use that

Comment: http://win7dl.com/dl-xcode-4.2/